# How to set hive.serialization.extend.nesting.levels property to true in spark?

Tags: json, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to convert json to dataframe, create temptable and perform some queries. However I'm getting the org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.SerDeException because the json has more than 7 nested levels. I tried setting that property to true  `hiveContext.sql("hive.serialization.extend.nesting.levels","true")`
But still getting the same issue. I'm using spark 1.6.1 version. Any help in resolving this will be helpful.

adding log
`ERROR log: error in initSerDe: org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.SerDeException Number of levels of nesting supported for LazySimpleSerde is 7 Unable to work with level 9. Use hive.serialization.extend.nesting.levels serde property for tables using LazySimpleSerde.
org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.SerDeException: Number of levels of nesting supported for LazySimpleSerde is 7 Unable to work with level 9. Use hive.serialization.extend.nesting.levels serde property for tables using LazySimpleSerde.`

Thanks

Comment: Can you post the log  because as the Jira-9500 upto 24 levels are supported. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-9500

Comment: added log @RajatMishra

Answer (score 0):

If the external table is defined as follows:

```
create external table t1
(
 a int,
 b double,
 c array<struct<
          k1:struct<
                     p1:struct<
                              r1:struct<
                                        h1:struct<
                                                  s1:array<struct<
                                                                  j1:struct<
                                                                            x1:int
                                                                           >
                                                        >>
                                              >
                                     >
                            >
                    >
         >>

 )
 ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'
 WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ( "mapping.time_stamp" = "timestamp" ) 
 LOCATION '/user/user1/staging/data/populationdata'
  ;
```

Suppose the data contains nested levels of more than 7.

Then in the next step, flatten the table as,

```
 create table t1
 ROW FORMAT SERDE   'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe' 
 WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ( 'hive.serialization.extend.nesting.levels'='true' )
 as
 select
   a, 
   b, 
   c1.k1
 from 
   t1
 lateral view explode(c) subview as c1
 ;
```